# Microsite default URL

Tags: marketing-cloud, url

I have created a new business unit in a common parent business unit.  I have created a microsite in the new business unit.  This business unit does not have the same default URL as the other.  I can not find any configuration option for this.  Is there any way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact SFMC Support and verify [Sender-Authentication Package](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/sender_authentication_package/) configuration.

Also, here's a breakdown of the configuration steps:

[Personalized URL for a Landing Page (CloudPages)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/127295/5202)