# How can I pass data to a Salesforce Marketing Cloud Smart Capture form via URL parameters?

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

Not sure this is possible with Marketing Cloud Smart Capture form and landing pages, but seems like it should be.

I'm working with a client who has more than 50 locations. Their website(s) is a WordPress multi-site installation, with a site for each location.

Client wants to use a Smart Capture form on a landing page. Rather than create a landing page/form for each location, I'd like to pass the location name in the URL from the link on the WordPress location site to a single MC landing page.

Assuming I name the field in my data extension "Location", how would I build the URLs and how would I populate either the form field or the data extension record that's created from the form submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is briefly explained in the [Smart Capture documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/). In short, you will need to:

1. Pass the location name as a URL parameter to the landing page, for example, http://pages.example.com?location=sydney
2. Create a hidden form field in your Smart Capture form named 'location'
3. Use the AMPscript `RequestParameter()` function to retrieve the value of the URL parameter.

Here is some sample code:

```
%%[
var @location
set @location = RequestParameter("location")
]%%

<!-- include in your form -->
  <input name="location" type="hidden" value="%%=v(@location)=%%" />
```

You will then create/update the 'location' Data Extension field with this hidden form field value.

Comment: We are having the issue that the Content Builder somehow adds spaces between value="%%=v(@location)=%%." It then looks like this in the HTML editor: value="    %%=v(@location)=%%" Is anyone else experiencing this issue and know how to solve that?