# Accessing subscriberkey from a Cloud Page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

So I've been through [this question and the answers](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/191474/amp-script-not-rendered-in-cloud-page?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#), but am still having some trouble building a CloudPage that retrieves SubscriberKey from the URL.  It works if I hardcode a Salesforce record ID as "@Id":

```
%%[
var @Id, @firstName, @lastName, @email, @subscriberRows, @subscriberRow, @OptIn, @OptOut
set @Id = "0030O00002GHNIvQAP"

IF RequestParameter("submitted") != true THEN

set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
 "Contact",
 "FirstName,LastName,Email,HasOptedInToEmail__c,HasOptedOutOfEmail",
 "Id", "=", @Id )
]%%
```

but if I try to "retrieve" the subscriberkey as described elsewhere

```
%%[
var @Id, @firstName, @lastName, @email, @subscriberRows, @subscriberRow, @OptIn, @OptOut
set @Id = RequestParameter("Subscriberkey")

IF RequestParameter("submitted") != true THEN

set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
 "Contact",
 "FirstName,LastName,Email,HasOptedInToEmail__c,HasOptedOutOfEmail",
 "Id", "=", @Id )
]%%
```

The page doesn't preview and if I go ahead and publish it I get an Internal Server Error when I go to the URL.  The page is a CloudPage Landing Page, and I have created a link in an email using the Cloud Page - Landing Page link function.  the HTML produced in the email looks like this:

```
<a alias="" conversion="false" data-linkto="cloudpageslandingpage" href="%%=CloudPagesURL(176)=%%" style="color:#808080;text-decoration:none;" title="">Simplified page</a>
```

Comment: I believe subscriberkey is unique to marketing cloud.  When pulling from sales cloud, I think you have to use contactid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're arriving at a CloudPage from a [**CloudPagesURL()**](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl) link in an email, then you can retrieve the `_subscriberKey` [**personalization string**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5) with [**AttributeValue()**](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue):

```ampscript
%%[

set @Id = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")

IF RequestParameter("submitted") != true THEN

set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects(
 "Contact",
 "FirstName,LastName,Email,HasOptedInToEmail__c,HasOptedOutOfEmail",
 "Id", "=", @Id )
]%%
```

Here's an example that I keep as a reminder:

```ampscript
%%[

  set @p1 = AttributeValue("PersonalizationStringName")
  set @p2 = RequestParameter("FormPostVariableName")
  set @p2 = QueryParameter("URLParameterName")

]%%
@p1: %%=v(@p1)=%%
<br>@p2: %%=v(@p2)=%%
<br>@p3: %%=v(@p3)=%%
```

**20180509 Edit**: clarification per [**@Eliot's**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper) comment

Comment: Yes, this will work, as long as you are using the [CloudPagesURL function](https://ampscript.guide/book/?section=cloudpagesurl) as the link in your email (or if you select the CloudPage from the Content Builder interface, which builds the CloudPagesURL function for you).